# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'

Tags: python, scikit-image

This is my code:

```
from skimage import io,color
filename = io.imread("input00.jpg")
img = color.rgb2gray(filename,as_grey=True)
io.imshow(img)
io.show()
```

Throws error at line 2 saying:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readImg.py", line 2, in <module>
  filename = io.imread("input00.jpg")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/_io.py", line 97, in imread
img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 209, in    call_plugin
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9- intel.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2198, in imread
  return _imread(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.4.x-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/matplotlib/image.py", line 1249, in imread
  'more images' % list(six.iterkeys(handlers.keys)))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.7.2-py2.7.egg/six.py", line 547, in   iterkeys
  return iter(d.iterkeys(**kw))
 AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'
```

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback?

Comment: `color.rgb2gray` does not take  any keyword arguments

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Even without the line color.rgb2gray line it doesn't work.

Comment: how did you install skimage?

Comment: Using this: sudo pip install -U scikit-image
It's in the documentation

Comment: You can also use those plugins directly: from skimage import io; io.imread('myfile.jpg', plugin='pil'); (other plugins include freeimage, qt, matplotlib).

Answer (score 6):

got the same problem. Solution was to install Pillow (you can do it from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)

Answer (score 0):

The relevant bit of code seems to be:

```
if ext not in handlers:
    im = pilread(fname)
    if im is None:
        raise ValueError('Only know how to handle extensions: %s; '
                         'with PIL installed matplotlib can handle '
                         'more images' % list(six.iterkeys(handlers.keys)))
    return im
```

So I think you're facing two problems.

(1) For some reason (possibly the absence of pillow?) you can't handle jpg files.

(2) There's a bug in `matplotlib`, so the error message isn't getting printed out because it has an error.  (!)

Instead of

```
>>> list(six.iterkeys(handlers.keys))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-13-2e5e3ad4f63f>", line 1, in <module>
    list(six.iterkeys(handlers.keys))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 490, in iterkeys
    return iter(getattr(d, _iterkeys)(**kw))
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'
```

they should have used

```
>>> list(six.iterkeys(handlers))
['png']
```

and passed the `handlers` dictionary directly.

Comment: I don't have Pillow installed. I am trying to install it but it throws some error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem also occurs in my project. My solution is removing Pillow first (`sudo apt-get remove python-pil`; of course, if you have not installed Pillow, please install it first of all, then test), then reinstall Pillow (`sudo apt-get install python-pil`), and the problem is solved!